# pgAdmin4, error al crear el servidor

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Acabo de instalar pgAdmin y cuando creo un servidor me da el siguiente error:

"unable to connect to server connection timeout expired"

La configuración del servidor es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Disculpen, me habia faltado instalar el Postgres. Crei que la instalacion del pgAdmin instalaba tambien el motor. Lo instale y funciono todo bien. Recien comienzo a usar esa base de datos